# LeakCanary spots Android WebView memory leak

Tags: android, memory-leaks, webview, garbage-collection, leakcanary

I've been using the a tool [leakcanary](https://github.com/square/leakcanary) to spot memory leakages in my application. It seems my WebViewActivity leaks everytime.

I created a simple application to test the leakages. I start a Activity with a WebView inside xml layout file/inflate with activity context. Js off. Everything default expect a simple webViewClient keeping redirection within the WebView. It leaks every time.

I've done plenty of research, the only way to prevent this is start WebViewActivity with another process and kill it inside onDestroy. But this method has its own disadvantages.

The leak happens every time on all my devices running 5.0+, haven't checked with 4.3 and below.

The leak info is pasted below:

> In com.example.webviewmemoryleaktest:1.0:1.
>   * com.example.webviewmemoryleaktest.WebViewActivity has leaked:
>   * GC ROOT android.os.ResultReceiver$MyResultReceiver.this$0
>   * references org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore$2$1.this$1 (anonymous class extends android.os.ResultReceiver)
>   * references org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore$2.this$0
>   * references org.chromium.content.browser.ContentViewCore.mContext
>   * references com.android.webview.chromium.ResourcesContextWrapperFactory$WebViewContextWrapper.mBase
>   * leaks com.example.webviewmemoryleaktest.WebViewActivity instance
>
> - Reference Key: 9a0346cf-6ad9-4b07-9329-a975d8fa3cbe
> - Device: LGE google Nexus 4 occam
> - Android Version: 5.1 API: 22
> - Durations: watch=5139ms, gc=188ms, heap dump=2822ms, analysis=30918ms

Appreciate if anyone could help. Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/square/leakcanary/issues/92#issuecomment-102181372 -- they have a documented procedure for dealing with leaks based on Android framework code. This is also covered [in the LeakCanary documentation](https://github.com/square/leakcanary#my-leak-is-caused-by-the-android-sdk-implementation).

Comment: Do you call `WebView.destroy()` [doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#destroy()) when you no longer need WebView and have removed it from the views hierarchy?

Comment: Yes, I did mWebView.destroy()/mWebView = null/mWebView.load(about:blank), none of them works for me.

Comment: did you find any workaround for this and did you report it to Google? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: I am too. It looks like it was supposed to be fixed in Chromium 42 (https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=473146) but my System WebView is on 44 and the leak still occurs.

Comment: Oh I just saw that @Allison How do you find out the version of Chromium? That's also interesting

Answer (score 0):

```
private ResultReceiver mResultReceiver = new ResultReceiver(new Handler()) {
    @Override
    public void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
        getContentViewClient().onImeStateChangeRequested(
                resultCode == InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN
                || resultCode == InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN);
        if (resultCode == InputMethodManager.RESULT_SHOWN) {
            // If OSK is newly shown, delay the form focus until
            // the onSizeChanged (in order to adjust relative to the
            // new size).
            // TODO(jdduke): We should not assume that onSizeChanged will
            // always be called, crbug.com/294908.
            getContainerView().getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(
                    mFocusPreOSKViewportRect);
        } else if (hasFocus() && resultCode
                == InputMethodManager.RESULT_UNCHANGED_SHOWN) {
            // If the OSK was already there, focus the form immediately.
            assert mWebContents != null;
            mWebContents.scrollFocusedEditableNodeIntoView();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public ResultReceiver getNewShowKeyboardReceiver() {
    return mResultReceiver;
}
```

make mResultReceiver to be private.